# text search in javascript?

Tags: javascript, full-text-search

I have a page with more than 200 links with this kind of formatting.

```
<h1>
  <a href="somelink">Somelink</a>
  some text that explain the meaning of the link. 
</h1>
```

Now, to make it bit easy to search through this link, i have put a search box.

My requirement is to search through all this tag and find the links that are relevant to 
the search box and hiding rest of the link.

How to do it in javascript ? ( i know basic javascript/jquery stuff but How to do full text search ? ) I do not required sorting according to relevant, just filter and show hide is good enough.

Comment: Are all of them in h1 tags by chance?

Comment: there are multiple h1 tags, 200 to last count. I do not wanted a server side search for speed reasons, and combined size of all 200 links hardly cross 10 kb.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hopefully you find this useful.  It probably is not the elegant or most efficient but it will let you enter multiple search terms and gives partial matches (which may or may not be wanted).  The way I have made it when you click the search button it will hide all other elements except ones matching either of your search terms but you can modify this to do whatever you want with the elements in the results Array.  I don't recommend using this exactly but hopefully it will give you a point of reference on how you may want to implement your own (if you choose to go with a solution other than the quicksearch).

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' language='javascript' >
$(document).ready(function() {
    var links = new Array();
    $("h1").each(function(index, element) {         
        links.push({
            text: $(this).text(),
            element: element
        });
    });

    $("#searchButton").click(function() {
        var query = $("#searchBox").val();
        var queryTerms = query.split(' ');

        var results = new Array();
        for(var i = 0; i < queryTerms.length; i++) {
            for(var j = 0; j < links.length; j++) {
                if (links[j].text.indexOf(queryTerms[i]) > -1) {
                    results.push(links[j].element);                     
                    }
            }
        }

        $("h1").each(function(index, element) {
            this.style.display = 'none';
        });
        for(var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
            results[i].style.display = 'block';
        }

    });     

});
</script>

</head>
<body>
<p>
<input id="searchBox" type="text" />
<input type="button" id="searchButton" value="Search" />
</p>

<h1>
  <a href="somelink">Somelink1</a>
  asdf
</h1>
<h1>
  <a href="somelink">Somelink2</a>
  ssss
</h1>
<h1>
  <a href="somelink">Somelink3</a>
  3333
</h1>
<h1>
  <a href="somelink">Somelink4</a>
  232323
</h1>
<h1>
  <a href="somelink">Somelink5</a>
  fffff
</h1>

 </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 8):

You can enumerate all `h1` tags get inner html and do `indexOf` , or you can use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) it has a custom made [contains](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) functionality, which returns the elements having given text.

Here is an example copied from jQuery docs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div>John Resig</div>

<div>George Martin</div>
<div>Malcom John Sinclair</div>
<div>J. Ohn</div>


<script>
$("div:contains('John')").css("text-decoration", "underline");
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Wow, that is really nice, I didn't know about it!

Comment: So here I am working on a solution that involved building an array and then searching that array for the text, this makes my solution look bloated and retarded.  +1 for simplicity.

Comment: How does it work for multiple words ? ( does it breaks them down and search or search the whole string ? )

Comment: @iamgopal , this will search whole string, you can split search string and search multiple times.

Answer (score 3):

I found one.

http://github.com/riklomas/quicksearch

which uses regex for search.